# Populating a 4-D array in r

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to load data into a 4-D array and having some trouble. Here is the structure of the data and the code I'm using:

```
  X   CREPid Year Survey Habitat julien Clouds Precip Noise Wind y species
1 1 19990008 2012      1       1    151      1      1     1    1 1    AMGO
2 2 19990027 2012      1       2    173      3      1     1    1 1    AMGO
3 3 19990031 2012      1       1    139      1      1     2    3 0    AMGO
4 4 19990033 2012      1       1    181      3      1     1    1 1    AMGO
5 5 19990034 2012      1       1    181      2      1     2    2 1    AMGO
6 6 19990037 2012      1       1    139      1      1     1    1 1    AMGO

# Format data in a spreadsheet format into a 4d array
# Determine required dimensions of 4d array
nsite <- length(unique(df$site))    # Number of sites (242)
nvisit <- length(unique(df$visit))  # Number of surveys or visits(3 per year)
nyear <- length(unique(df$year))    # Number of years(4 years)
nspec <- length(unique(df$species)) # Number of species (46 species)

# Prepare array and pre-fill array with NAs
BigArray2 <- array(NA, dim = c(nsite, nvisit, nyear, nspec))

# Fill array with the detection/nondetection data
# Loop over all rows in the spreadsheet data and fill them in 
#   at the right place in the 4d array

for(i in 1:nrow(CREPallOccFinal)){
BigArray2[CREPallOccFinal$CREPid[i], CREPallOccFinal$Survey[i], CREPallOccFinal$Year[i], CREPallOccFinal$species[i]]<- CREPallOccFinal$y[i]}
```

However, every time I run the code, I get this error message:

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, CREPallOccFinal$CREPid[i], CREPallOccFinal$Survey[i],  : 
>     subscript out of bounds

I cant figure out the problem, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that the OP and @samadi made conflicting edits.  The variables used to define nsite, nvisit and nyear are wrong right now.

Comment: There is no enough information to be able to help.

Comment: What other information would be needed? Ive included the coding and sample data...

Comment: E.g. for `CREPid` you use `19990008` but it can only be in the range of 1-242.

Comment: I need to recode the site names to 1-242? I guess I need to do the same with species then too? and year?

Comment: You need to do this also with `year` and maybe also the others, as long as they are not in the range `1-length(unique(x))`, or you access them by name and not by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used indexes outside the allowed range. E.g. for CREPid you use 19990008 but it can only be in the range of 1-242. An example how you can create your array is shown below.

First extract all levels of keys with `unique`. Then create your array as you have done it, but I also define `dimnames`, which enables access by name. To get indices for the array I use `match` which returns the index where it found a given value.

```
#Creaete data
set.seed(7)
n  <- 1e4
x  <- data.frame(id=sample(10:252, n, TRUE), survey=sample(1:3, n, TRUE)
  , year=sample(2012:2015, n, TRUE), species=sample(letters, n, TRUE)
  , y=runif(n, 0, 3))
head(x)
#   id survey year species         y
#1  51      2 2014       o 1.0825328
#2 220      3 2015       f 2.1976835
#3 168      2 2014       f 0.9047656
#4 229      3 2012       t 2.1546260
#5 112      3 2015       c 2.8865230
#6 203      1 2013       l 1.4364280

#Unique levels of keys
tid  <- unique(x$id)
tsurvey  <- unique(x$survey)
tyear  <- unique(x$year)
tspecies  <- unique(x$species)

#Create array
arr <- array(NA
  , dim = c(length(tid), length(tsurvey), length(tyear), length(tspecies))
  , dimnames = list(tid, tsurvey, tyear, tspecies))

#Fill array
arr[matrix(c(match(x$id,tid), match(x$survey,tsurvey), match(x$year,tyear)
  , match(x$species,tspecies)), ncol=4)] <- x$y

#Get from array by name
arr["51","2","2014","o"]
#[1] 1.082533
```

Comment: Much appreciated!